# Slicing geometry with geodjango based on another geometry

Tags: django, geodjango

I have a PostgreSQL database set up and am using Geodjango to interact with the geometry saved in this database. My use case is as follows:

- In the database, I have a complicated, large multi-polygon containing all the parks in the country. **This is contained in a single geometry field**.
- I have another record that contains the boundaries of my region.
- What I want to do is somehow truncate/slice the multi-polygon so that it removes those that are not within the boundaries.

Sample code:

```
region = Shapefile.objects.get(pk=1)
region_boundaries = region.geometry # this contains the boundaries for the region

all_parks_in_country = Shapefile.objects.get(pk=2)
parks = all_parks_in_country.geometry # and this one now has all the national parks

sliced_geometry = ...
# .... And here is where I am stuck!
```

I am providing visuals below. Note that I am trying to get the sliced geometry in the views, in Python -- once I have it there I will then use it as needed (show it in the HTML files or whatever is needed).

The first map shows the entire country and in green the national parks.

[image: First map]

The second map shows, in purple outline, the boundaries of my region.

[image: Second map, outline of region]

Third map showing in red those (parts of!) the national parks multi-polygon that should ideally be 'cut out' of the national geometry.

[image: Third map, in red the cutouts]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have isolated the geometries you can use the GEOS API [`intersection`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#django.contrib.gis.geos.GEOSGeometry.intersection) method on them.

The method:

> Returns a GEOSGeometry representing the points shared by this geometry and "other".

So you can take the "sliced" geom as follows:

```
sliced_geometry = parks.intersection(region_boundaries)
```

Comment: This is 100% amazing... so simple, fast and exactly what I was trying to do... THANKS!

Comment: @user74934 Happy to help :D